# What’s the reason behind having to use specifically animal skin for klaf?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, animals, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, safrus

What’s the reasoning behind the need to use animals per se as opposed to any other paperlike material for klaf (to write on)? Is there significance in the need to take the life of an animal for the mitzvot of mezuza/tefillin/sefer torah/etc?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yitz and thanks for this first question. 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Hope to see you around!

Comment: Those years this was the best choice with respect to cost and durability?

Comment: I’m asking less from a pragmatic standpoint and more from a metahalakhic standpoint.

Comment: http://heebnvegan.blogspot.co.il/2009/12/use-of-animal-products-in-jewish-ritual.html seems to indicate that is is a basic tradition (given to Moses at Sinai)

Comment: You don't have to take a life.  It could have died on it's own.

Comment: _"The entire purpose of creation is to serve Man so he gets closer to Gcd; thus elevating the non-humans in the process. This is an example of elevating an animal to Kodesh status"_. Is that the type of answer you're looking for?

Comment: The animal could have been slaughtered for meat or (way back when) sacrifice, no? Who would eat the skin?  There's always been a sizable leather industry that probably made use of the skins, also.